# Rails 4.0, resolving query placeholders, using helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use a helper function, filling in the where clause

In my view I have the line

```
<%= f.collection_select(:artikelgroep_id, Artikelgroep.where(artikelgroeps_not_in_users_selection), :id, :omschrijving) %>
```

In the helper:

```
module ArtikelgroepsHelper
  def artikelgroeps_not_in_users_selection
    a1='"id NOT IN (SELECT artikelgroep_id FROM user_artikelgroeps WHERE user_id = :uid)"'  + "," +  "{uid: @user.id}"
 end
end
```

When I perform the view I get the message:

> ```
> SELECT `artikelgroeps`.* FROM `artikelgroeps`  WHERE ("id NOT IN (SELECT artikelgroep_id FROM user_artikelgroeps WHERE user_id = :uid)",{uid: @user.id})
> ```

It seems thet the placeholder is not resolved.

When I directly fill in the result of the helper in stead of artikelgroeps_not_in_users_selection, it is working fine.

How can I force the placeholders being resolved??

Comment: This is all wrong, use a scope instead of trying to return arguments from a method so that you can forward them to a `where`.

Comment: See the Rails guides on [ActiveRecord Querying # Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions). Look for how `where('condition = ?', 'what_i_am_looking_for')` is used.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm This is a deeper misunderstanding of how Ruby (and all other languages) work; he's returning the *string* `'"id not in...", "{uid: user.id}"'`, expecting that `where(returned_string)` is somehow equivalent to `where("id not in ...", {uid: user.id}).`  Bart, you cannot pass around strings of code and have them evaluated later, by Ruby, just by passing them as arguments to an arbitrary function. This is pretty far off from how this actually works.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to do this (use a scope instead), but to make it work, you need to return an array of arguments from your method, and pass them to `where` with `send`:

```
module ArtikelgroepsHelper
  def artikelgroeps_not_in_users_selection
    ['"id NOT IN (SELECT artikelgroep_id FROM user_artikelgroeps WHERE user_id = :uid)"', {uid: @user.id}]
  end
end

Artikelgroep.send(:where, *artikelgroeps_not_in_users_selection)
```

Instead of all this, you should just define a scope:

```
class Artikelgroep < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope not_in_users_selection, (user_id) ->
    where('id NOT IN (SELECT artikelgroep_id FROM user_artikelgroeps WHERE user_id = ?)', user_id)
    # OR 
    where('id NOT IN (?)', UserArtikelgroeps.where(user_id: user_id).pluck(:id))
end

# Usage:
Artikelgroep.not_in_users_select(@user.id)
```

Comment: Thanks meagar, I also prefer the scope otion. But I am trying helper methods also, so that I am able to contruct complex queries

Comment: @@meagar, it works when it is written as: scope :not_in_users_selection, -> (user_id) {.......}

Comment: After clearing my database I got a ID not in (NULL) issue. I solved this issue by adding << 0: where('id NOT IN (?)', UserArtikelgroeps.where(user_id: user_id).pluck(:id))<<0. When the selection in UserArtikelgroeps is empty, ActiveRecord generates id NOT in (0), which is a valid SQL statement because all ID's are greater than 0

Answer (score 1):

Put the query in your model:

#### model

```
model Artikelgroep
  scope :without_user, (user) -> {
    joins(:user_artikelgroeps).where("user_artikelgroeps.user_id != ?", user.id)
  }
end
```

#### view

```
<%= f.collection_select(:artikelgroep_id, Artikelgroep.without_user(@user), :id, :omschrijving) %>
```

Comment: @BartvanLeeuwen both queries should work, though mine might need tweaking as I don't have your application in front of me. The difference is my query uses a join and a simple `user_id != user.id` whereas the others select all `artikelgroeps` without `user.id` and then do a `NOT IN (1,2,3)` query.